# Why isn't the 'k' increasing in it's value?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, algorithm

I am trying to convert the **ROMAN numerical into integers** using python and I am facing trouble in writing this `for` loop. My **CODE** is as follows:

```
def romanToInt(s: str) -> int:
        sarr = [x for x in s]
        symbolBank = {
            'I' : 1,
            'V' : 5,
            'X' : 10,
            'L' : 50,
            'C' : 100,
            'D' : 500,
            'M' : 1000
        }
        prefixBank = {
            'I' : 1,
            'X' : 10,
            'C' : 100,
        }
        suffixBank = {
            'V' : 5,
            'X' : 10,
            'L' : 50,
            'C' : 100,
            'D' : 500,
            'M' : 1000
        }
        result = 0

        for k in range(len(sarr) - 1):
            print(k)
            if (sarr[k] in prefixBank) and (sarr[k+1] in suffixBank):
                value = suffixBank[sarr[k + 1]] - prefixBank[sarr[k]]
                literal = sarr[k] + sarr[k + 1]
                k += 1
            else:
                value = symbolBank[sarr[k]]
                literal = sarr[k]
            print('literal:', literal, 'value:', value)
            result += value

        if len(literal) < 2:
            value = prefixBank[sarr[len(sarr) - 1]]
            result += value
            
        return result
```

and the **OUTPUT** for the above program is as follows:

```
0
literal: M value: 1000
1
literal: CM value: 900
2
literal: M value: 1000
3
literal: XC value: 90
4
literal: C value: 100
5
literal: IV value: 4
3094
```

I want to know why `k += 1` is not working inside the `if` statement.
I meant to ask - why is it not skipping the "literals" `M` and `C` after `CM` and `XC`

Comment: you have a preceding for statement  ```for k in range(len(sarr) - 1):```, the value of k is updated based on it's previous value, the statement within the for loop ```k += 1``` will update K but it will imediately be returned to the value in the for loop + 1, at the next execution of the for statement.

Comment: K is increased, however on the next iteration of the loop K will be set again to the next value from range.

Answer (score 0):

The value `k` is an iterator.  Your `k += 1` is doomed.  When the loop begins the next iteration, that `k += 1` will not count.

Comment: Got it! Used a while loop instead. Thanks